# My SPF record seems to be passed but still going to spambox

Tags: spam-prevention, mail-server, mass-emails

I am sending email with swiftmailer, All of them goes to the spam folder, The SPF shows the status pass. what could be the changes i need to do to unspam it

```
 Delivered-To: josemon.zixent@gmail.com
 Received: by 10.107.191.131 with SMTP id p125csp117228iof;
    Tue, 18 Oct 2016 22:20:57 -0700 (PDT)
 X-Received: by 10.55.18.28 with SMTP id c28mr4620542qkh.125.1476854457365;
    Tue, 18 Oct 2016 22:20:57 -0700 (PDT)
 Return-Path: <tips@interviewtips.xyz>
Received: from interviewtips.xyz (li1017-172.members.linode.com. [45.33.71.172])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id w74si23142432qkw.3.2016.10.18.22.20.57
    for <josemon.zixent@gmail.com>;
    Tue, 18 Oct 2016 22:20:57 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of tips@interviewtips.xyz designates 45.33.71.172 as permitted sender) client-ip=45.33.71.172;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of tips@interviewtips.xyz designates 45.33.71.172 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=tips@interviewtips.xyz
Received: by interviewtips.xyz (Postfix, from userid 1001) id B36DE817B9; Wed, 19 Oct 2016 05:20:54 +0000 (UTC)
To: josemon.zixent@gmail.com
Subject: [josemon.zixent] Is your Resume not getting shortlisted?

X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:SimpleMailInvoker.php
Message-ID: <a6d39b3f95ee3608da294edc48eee3e7@interviewtips.xyz>
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 05:20:54 +0000
From: tips@interviewtips.xyz
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;           boundary="_=_swift_v4_1476854454_e4fa42ac587c6d9e0a47f9b64d71b9ec_=_"
tips: tips@interviewtips.xyz

--_=_swift_v4_1476854454_e4fa42ac587c6d9e0a47f9b64d71b9ec_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
--_=_swift_v4_1476851958_4161d478461e54e72c39c80d6e24bfa1_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: The receiving service probably thinks the subject/body are spammy in that case. Try changing those.

Comment: Tried that, set subject to "Good day jose" , and content to "
Good day dear, this is the best time we can go to the class " 

No effect

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.  See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Comment: The body parts seem to be mangled and you don't have a trailing MIME boundary.  The apparently empty header line after the Subject header  looks suspicious, too.  If you copy/paste email code without understanding it, you are behaving like a spammer.  The .xyz domain name has a heavy spam association as well.

Comment: thanks for the mention , I am closing the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want your emails not to get in spam you need a few more things than just an SPF record. Specially when you are sending mails to Windows or Google you need to have a good reputation. They got spam filters wich will add you to the spam folder quickly if you have a small problem with your reputation.

Get some more information about the following protocols if you want to get a good repu:

- SPF
- DKIM
- DMARC
- PTR

There are a lot of domain checking tools you can find by googling.

I prefer this: http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/